I have paid one month rent to book an apartment, but I want to delay signing the contract
I have paid one month's rent in order to book an apartment in Delft, Netherlands, through a housing platform. They have sent me a contract where it is stated that it has 3 months notice. I would like to delay signing it for about a month before I move in. Is it possible that I can lose the booking, even though I have already paid?

What platform is that?

Actually the booking is for the 15th of August. This is the agreement and it is also stated in the contract, which I have not signed yet. The problem is that if I sign it now, 2,5 months before I move in, this means that if something happens until then, I will have to pay at least 2 more months rent,because of the 3 months notice clause Isn’t that right? That is why I want to delay for a while.

As far as I know, the rental market is still very tight in Delft, especially for smaller apartments. So if you are not prepared to move in by the date required by the landlord, then there is indeed a high risk they can pick someone else. The landlord would just look at the month where the apartment is sitting empty as lost income, when you actually move in doesn't really matter to them.
I cannot comment on the terms and conditions of some unnamed platform but it's difficult to see how paying and not signing the lease can help you finesse your way out of this. Either both you and the landlord are already bound by the lease and then you owe rent from the original date and can only get out of it in three months from now. Or they're not bound by the lease either and they can just refund your payment.
Note that there is nothing that prevents you from signing a lease today with a starting date in the future. I have done this in the past. So you have no reason to delay the signing per se and what you are asking is essentially whether you can force your (future) landlord to accept a new starting date for the lease or foregoing the first month's rent without actually discussing it with them, which is not a great way to start.
